# Fill select options without duplications with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

How i can fill the select-options with the data of my array without getting duplicates?

For example the role "user" should be listed only one time.

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-model="roleSelect" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td><strong>{{user.name}}</strong></td>
            <td><select ng-options="role as user.role for user in users"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$scope.users = 

        [{
            "name": "user1", 
            "role": "user"
        },
        {
            "name": "user2", 
            "role": "admin"
        },
        {
            "name": "user3", 
            "role": "user"
        },
        {
            "name": "user4", 
            "role": "moderator"
        }];
```

Is it possible to add a filter?  Or how would you do this? A second question is, how can I mark the selected roles with ng-option?

here is a Fiddle with some bugs :(

http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/EH46S/2/

Comment: what is "mark the selected roles"?

Comment: set the role content as selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/86eUX/1/)

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
      return  _.uniq(input,false,function(input){return input.role;});
    };
});
```

Unique filter is been added. I have used **underscorejs** library for getting unique values.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you, is it possible to set the current state as selected?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Do you need to set some value as selected?

Comment: yes :-) for example for user1 user should be selected!

Comment: I do not know how to do with ng-repeat. http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/2bP43/1/ . see this fiddle which may help you.

Comment: Good Morning :D I found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nofear87/cppfk/1/ Now in need the selected value in my selectChange Function. Do you have an idea? ng-model="user.name" not working :(

Comment: I have another question: Why i need to pass the 'role' here: 'unique : 'role'. What is passed to the input of the unique function? Maybe you can explain it to me :-)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle according to your need. http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/ugLQt/3/ . please go through that fiddle and analyse. We need to send the role since the filter is coded in such a way that it filters based on the key of the map that we are sending

Comment: Thanks! But it works in the same way, when i delete  : 'role' in 'unique : 'role'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52163/discussion-between-user2380695-and-nofear87)

Answer (score 2):

You fetch all the information from the same model, so you can have a result with the following [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EH46S/3/):

```
<select ng-model="roleSelect" ng-options="usr.role for usr in users"></select>
```

Take time to read the docs if a component doesn't works... It's really helpful!

Note that you should have your roles stored in a separate model.

And yes, you can add a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) using the form `...for role in roles | yourRoleFilter`

Good luck.